# Significance of ^ and ! operators in C

Tags: c

The value of `k` comes out to be 2. I edited the problem and found that `(!i^j)`  and `(i^!j)` gives value 0 but `(!i^!j)` gives value 1. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{ 
    int i = 1, j = 0, k; 
    k = (i ^ j) + (!i ^ j) + (i ^ !j) + (!i ^ !j); 
    printf("%d",k); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the `!` ([logical not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation)) and `^` ([XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)) operators do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got four expressions here, each producing 1 or 0. The overall expression adds up the ones.

Here are the expressions with `i` and `j` substituted by their respective values:

```
 1 ^  0 //  i ^  j
!1 ^  0 // !i ^  j
 1 ^ !0 //  i ^ !j
!1 ^ !0 // !i ^ !j
```

Precedence of unary NOT `!` is higher than that of binary XOR `^`, so `^` computations end up like this:

```
1 ^ 0 --> 1 //  i ^  j
0 ^ 0 --> 0 // !i ^  j
1 ^ 1 --> 0 //  i ^ !j
0 ^ 1 --> 1 // !i ^ !j
```

This is because binary XOR `^` produces `1` only when exactly one of its parameters is `1`, and the other one is zero.

The first and last sub-expressions produce `1`; the ones in the middle produce `0`.

Answer (score 2):

`!` is the logaical NOT operator and `^` is the XOR operator so this is what's happening:

```
int i = 1, j = 0, k;
```

logical `NOT` operator:

(Don't mix up the logical NOT with the bitwise NOT!)

```
!1 -> 0
!0 -> 1
```

`XOR` operator:

```
0 ^ 0 -> 0
0 ^ 1 -> 1
1 ^ 0 -> 1
1 ^ 1 -> 0
```

---

1.`i ^ j`:

```
0000 0001 //i 
0000 0000 //j
--------- XOR ^
0000 0001 = 1 = k
```

2.`!i ^ j`:

```
1 //i
- NOT !
0 = 0

0000 0000 //i
0000 0000 //j
--------- XOR ^
0000 0000 = 0 = k
```

3.`i ^ !j`:

```
0 //j
- NOT !
1 = 1

0000 0001 //i
0000 0001 //j
--------- XOR ^
0000 0000 = 0 = k
```

4.`!i ^ !j`:

```
1 //i
- NOT !
0 = 0

0 //j
- NOT !
1 = 1

0000 0000 //i
0000 0001 //j
--------- XOR ^
0000 0001 = 1 = k
```

Answer (score 2):

For i =1, j =0

! == logical not operator

```
!i = 0
!j = 1
```

For i ^ j (read as i exor j, ^ is exor operator), truth table with different values of i and j would be:

```
i j i^j
0 0  0
0 1  1
1 0  1
1 1  0
```

See that for same i and i exor returns 0. So in your case `(!i^!j)` = 0 ^ 1 which from above truth table is 1 and hence its 1 that you see.